# Do you need Nginx / Apache for deploying an API?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, load-balancing

To my understanding, Nginx/Apache are used to a) serve static content like HTML pages and b) balance requests between servers. I am programming an API in Go. It doesn't need to serve static content and only runs on one machine.

Would Nginx/Apache be any useful here? Would there be a downside to just letting the Go application run on a single port?

Comment: Web servers do much more than that. Are you prepared to reimplement _everything_ you might need in your code that a web server already handles that you aren't even aware exists yet? For that matter, what happens if your app actually gets big and you need to run more than one copy of the API server?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you'll want a web server. Web servers are completely capable of running code behind the requests they process. Your preconception that only static content is served from web servers is not the case for most installations today.  Safe to say, every modern web site is serving up content from a dynamic source using a web server to host the application.

While some languages have built-in web servers, they will likely not be as robust or secure or feature rich, as modern web servers.

Comment: "need" is a bit strong. For years, OpenStack implemented its APIs without Apache or NGINX and used small Python libraries instead. Web servers have advantages but can be overkill for a small app.

Comment: What distinct advantages would a web server have in my case?

Comment: I think the scale and specific use case for this api will determine the advantages/lack of.